# TTTableViewController fill in dataSource with array of objects variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, three20

I have used the example of TTTableViewController to display an array that can have a variable number of rows / images / text. With the example given, the list of objects is hard-coded during initialization if the ViewController, for instance:

```
self.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
  @"Static Text",
  [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"TTTableItem"],
  [TTTableCaptionItem itemWithText:@"TTTableCaptionItem" caption:@"Text"],
  [TTTableSubtextItem itemWithText:@"TTTableSubtextItem" caption:kLoremIpsum],
  nil];
```

I want **not to display** a line if the content (that i get from another variable, let's say `kLoremIpsum` in the example above) is empty. To do so, I have tried:

```
NSMutableArray * myListOfRows;
myListOfRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
  @"Static Text",
  [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"TTTableItem"],
  [TTTableCaptionItem itemWithText:@"TTTableCaptionItem" caption:@"Text"],
  nil];

if( kLoremIpsum != nil ) {
    [myListOfRows addObject:[TTTableSubtextItem
                             itemWithText:@"TTTableSubtextItem"
                                  caption:kLoremIpsum]];
}

self.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
  myListOfRows, 
  nil];
```

But it does not work, my TTTableView remains completely empty. I can see that the table is properly working with the number of objects I expect. Why this code does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, where you call `[TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:]`, you pass it `myListOfRows`, which is an array; but the `dataSourceWithObjects:` function expects to be passed the actual objects, not an array object that points to the objects.

Call `dataSourceWithArrays` or `dataSourceWithItems` instead.  For example:

```
self.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithArrays:@"Static Text",
                   myListOfRows, nil];
```

Also, in the original example that you are copying from, `@"Static Text"` is not actually a row, it is a section title.  So in your code, you would not add this string to `myListOfRows`.  In other words, near the beginning of your code, you should remove the `@"Static Text"` line:

```
myListOfRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
  // @"Static Text", // <-- commented out this line!
  [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"TTTableItem"],
  [TTTableCaptionItem itemWithText:@"TTTableCaptionItem" caption:@"Text"],
  nil];
```

These different ways to initialize a `TTSectionedDataSource` are documented in `TTSectionedDataSource.h`:

```
/**
 * Objects should be in this format:
 *
 *   @"section title", item, item, @"section title", item, item, ...
 *
 * Where item is generally a type of TTTableItem.
 */
+ (TTSectionedDataSource*)dataSourceWithObjects:(id)object,...;

/**
 * Objects should be in this format:
 *
 *   @"section title", arrayOfItems, @"section title", arrayOfItems, ...
 *
 * Where arrayOfItems is generally an array of items of type TTTableItem.
 */
+ (TTSectionedDataSource*)dataSourceWithArrays:(id)object,...;

/**
 *  @param items
 *
 *    An array of arrays, where each array is the contents of a
 *    section, to be listed under the section title held in the
 *    corresponding index of the `section` array.
 *
 *  @param sections
 *
 *    An array of strings, where each string is the title
 *    of a section.
 *
 *  The items and sections arrays should be of equal length.
 */
+ (TTSectionedDataSource*)dataSourceWithItems:(NSArray*)items sections:(NSArray*)sections;
```

Comment: that's clear, eventually i need to use dataSourceWithItems to do what I want with 2 arrays. Thank you for the quality of your answer!